# Formulae.Combinators.permutations/2 wants an actual integer and not a variable

Tags: elixir

The code:

```
require Formulae.Combinators

def permutations(trains, train_stations)
    when is_list(trains) and
          is_list(train_stations) do
  number_of_trains = length(trains)
  Formulae.Combinators.permutations(train_stations, number_of_trains)
end
```

The error:

```
** (ArgumentError) ranges (first..last) expect both sides to be integers, got: 
{:number_of_trains, [line: 86], nil}..1
(elixir 1.10.2) lib/range.ex:63: Range.new/2
expanding macro: Formulae.Combinators.permutations/2
lib/trains.ex:86: Trains.permutations/2
```

But https://hexdocs.pm/formulae/Formulae.Combinators.html says the in `permutations(l, n)` n should be an integer and `length(trains)` returns an integer. `Formulae.Combinators.permutations(train_stations, 2)` works fine.

What is my mistake? How can I fix it?

Comment: Neither combinations nor permutations accept the dynamic value for a number. If you want to have it dynamically, you are responsible to generate clauses for the range of interest. Allowing any dynamic value is vulnerable to very long running process slowing down the VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, I have updated the library to support [dynamic numbers](https://hexdocs.pm/formulae/Formulae.Combinators.html#module-dynamic-numbers).

Use generated:

- [`Formulae.combinations/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/formulae/Formulae.html#combinations/2), and
- [`Formulae.permutations/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/formulae/Formulae.html#permutations/2).